# Company called my elderly mother to let her know that I have been fired. Is this fair?

Tags: india, termination

I was recently fired from my job. I continued to remain in the city for the next two months in order to search for new jobs and perhaps a tiny bit afraid to go back to my hometown and tell my parents that I had been laid off.

One day, at a networking event, I happened to run into a senior colleague who expressed his surprise at seeing me there as this was an industry networking event. I assured him that on me getting the invitation (these invitations are usually sent to people currently working in the industry) I had mentioned to the organizers that I am no longer working there and they had invited me nevertheless as I used to be a regular during my three years in the city. My colleague was not convinced.

The next day, I learned that the company had gone out of their way to let every such organization know that I had been fired and that I do not have connections to the industry anymore, including a call to my aged mother and father, who are now very disappointed in me. Another colleague also gave me a call and "advised" me to go back to my hometown.

How do I now find my way back and build a career in this industry?

Comment: Let's say it isn't. What are you going to do about it?

Comment: You may want to discuss with a lawyer if this is a breach of Indian privacy laws.

Comment: Next time keep your mouse shut or better yet, tell them it is none of their business. You do not own anyone apologises... would it also not be time to get more independent?

Comment: To be honest, based on some of the questions i have read here, the work culture and behaviour of businesses and employers in India is bizarre, often vindictive and  borderline farcical.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The bad news: There's nothing you can do about this legally. The good news: You know now that your former boss is a first rate asshole, and everyone he contacted knows it as well. He tried to diminish your reputation; what he has managed is to destroy his. That kind of behaviour puts the company on everybody's "don't do business with them" list.

Actually, there is something you can do about the whole thing: Get a job that pays better than the old one. Once that's done you can call your friendly ex-collegue and ask him if he has got any raise recently. What you tell your parents: It's normal to lose a job. Happens to the best. In your case, they have seen what asshole your boss is. So they shouldn't be disappointed, they should be glad you escaped from a boss like that. There will be better jobs.

Comment: "The company did go out of their way"... Either the boss was involved, or his company is totally out of control. The consequences how to handle that company are identical - don't even touch it.

Comment: I had a fair share of differences with my line manager and I presume it is the line manager who had been making these calls. 

Line manager, who joined only recently, found me to be quite inexperienced to do what I was doing and delegated me to more admin jobs. This was fine at first, but then I was reported for having "shown extreme displeasure in doing assignments" which eventually got me fired.

Comment: If they are sharing information about your termination with others in the industry and doing so with more than just 'he was let go' then you may have grounds for a slander suit against them.  This is one reason why most companies don't do this.  You could probably get an employment lawyer to come up with a bunch of other things to throw at them due to them calling your parents.  Country specific here, some places have more protections than others.

Answer (score 8):

> Is this fair?

No, it's pretty malicious whatever the circumstances of you being let go. Particularly informing your parents. In smallish industries/communities it's not unknown for a former employer to inform other companies, but it's not nice.

Involving family is very unprofessional and nasty.

However there isn't a great deal you can do about it depending where you are. I'm in the third World so if things get personal I can stroll down to someones office and get personal back, but in some countries you'd get arrested.

Comment: I will say "most" countries